Explain the behavior of parent and child processes
So, recently I have been learning about processes, operating systems, etc. I have come across a problem that I simply can't wrap my head around. Here is the code to the said problem
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    int x = 10;
    int * ptr = &x;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        *ptr = *ptr + 10;
        printf("Child process x value is %d address of x is %d\n", *ptr, ptr);
    }
    else {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Child completed x value is %d address of x is %d\n", *ptr, ptr);
    }


    return 0;
}

In the above code I'm trying to achieve IPC without using IPC. I've used pointers to maintain consistency and I've declared it above the fork() call.
I was expecting the values to remain consistent, i.e. the value of x in the printf to be 20, to my Suprise it wasn't.
Here's the output:
./fork3
Child process x value is 20 address of x is -559321616
Child completed x value is 10 address of x is -559321616
I've even printed the address and its the same!!!
Help me out on this please

fork() creates a brand new address space. It is initially a copy of its parents' address space but is completely independent of it. Changes in parent don't affent chlid and changes in child don't affect parent. You apparently want to share addrss space between the two processes, so you might want to google on how to use clone3 call with CLONE_VM flag.
